# How can I limit class usage?

Tags: c#, .net, oop, inheritance

I have a list of `List<object>`. How can I limit that only `Class1` and `Class2` should be used there is list?

`Class1` and `Class2` are basically different. I would guess what there is basic class for both this classes and restrict List to only work with it, but really don't know.

Comment: `public abstract class ClassAbstract`. `public class Class1 : ClassAbstract`. `public class Class2 : ClassAbstract`. `List<ClassAbstract>`. You can do the same with interface.

Comment: You are looking for the concept called interface. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/87d83y5b%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Comment: How are you using the items in the list? Are you using `is` or `as` to see what to do with them? It just seems a little odd.

Answer (score 9):

Make an interface that both classes implement

```
public interface MyInterface 
{
}

public class Class1 : MyInterface
{
}

public class Class2 : MyInterface
{
}

List<MyInterface> myList = new List<MyInterface>();
```

The only instances of classes that can be referenced in the list are those that implement the `MyInterface` interface. In this case only `Class1` and `Class2`.

Comment: Note that "Class1 and Class2 are basically different", this may indicate the mutual interface approach does not work. :)

Comment: @David It's really is. There is no same things for `Class1` and `Class2`.

Comment: I disagree, they both share the aspect "need to go into the list". So that is their common attribute. The interface itself could be empty to reflect this. If they are so different that making an interface is out of the question, then making one list of both types doesn't make much sense either.

Comment: I agree with Bazzz. Check for [marker interface pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marker_interface_pattern)

Comment: @MehmetAtaş Thanks for your support and adding a relevant article.

Comment: This should work fine, because the List was originally of type `object` which means some casting is needed to use the objects in it anyway. Although, the whole idea seems a little suspect to me.

Comment: @kseen Bazzz's approach should suffice. If you think that both `Class1` and `Class2` are too different in such a way, why you want both of them share the same `List`? You can approach the same using 2 variable : `List<Class1> class1List` `List<Class2> class2List` though.

Comment: -, I could create another `MyInterface` inheritor and get access to the List.

Answer (score 2):

I'm convinced that [Bazz's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16707974/588868) **is the correct way** to handle such requirement.

There's however, another approach, that you can try :

```
public class MyCustomList : ArrayList
{
    public override void Add(object item){
        if(item is Class1 || item is Class2) {
            base.Add(item);
        }
        else {
            throw BadaboomException();
        }
    }
}
```

Or you can ensure signatures by wrapping the collection completely

```
public class MyCustomList : ICollection
{
    private readonly ArrayList m_InnerList = new ArrayList();

    public virtual void Add(Class1 item) {
        this.m_InnerList.Add(item);
    }
    public virtual void Add(Class2 item) {
        this.m_InnerList.Add(item);        
    }


    public void CopyTo(Array array, int index) { 
        m_InnerList.CopyTo(array, index);
    }

    public int Count { get { return m_InnerList.Count; } }
    public bool IsSynchronized { get{ return m_InnerList.IsSynchronized; } }
    public object SyncRoot { get{ return m_InnerList.SyncRoot; } }

    public IEnumerator GetEnumerator(){
        return m_InnerList.GetEnumerator();
    }

}
```